# Using MaTeX with Callout

Tags: labeling, matex

Recently, I tried to use `Callout` with the `MaTeX` objects.
`MaTeX` is a package I downloaded in the following link 
http://szhorvat.net/pelican/latex-typesetting-in-mathematica.html

My test code is the following.

```
Plot[ Callout[ x, MaTeX["A=2", FontSize -> 40], Scaled[0.5]] , {x, 1,   10}]
```

I wanted to control the size of label by specifying the `FontSize->40`. However, `Callout` seems to rescale the size of the label. Is there a way to manually change the size of `MaTeX` object within `Callout` environment?

Comment: When you ask about MaTeX here, feel free to also drop a note in the Gitter channel: https://gitter.im/MaTeX-help/Lobby I didn't see this question when it was posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you are using Mathematica 11.3.  The resizing you observe is due to the new [`LabelingSize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LabelingSize.html) feature.

The default is `LabelingSize -> Automatic`, which limits the size of graphics and images (but not text) in labels. MaTeX output is always a `Graphics` expression, thus it is resized by default.  The workaround is `LabelingSize -> Full`.

```
Plot[Callout[x, MaTeX["A=2", FontSize -> 32], Scaled[1/2]], {x, 1, 10}, LabelingSize -> Full]
```

[image]

You may not want to use this workaround when you *also* have actual images/graphics that you use as labels, and you want *those* to be auto-scaled, but not the MaTeX labels.  An alternative workaround is to wrap the MaTeX output with `Pane` (or similar) so that it won't be detected as `Graphics`.

```
Plot[Callout[x, Pane@MaTeX["A=2", Magnification -> 3], Scaled[1/2]], {x, 1, 10}]
```

In versions earlier than 11.3, these workarounds are not needed, as no automatic label scaling is done.  I will add a note about this potential problem to the MaTeX documentation.  Thanks for the feedback!

---

A note on `Magnification` vs `FontSize` in `MaTeX`:

- `FontSize` is passed down to LaTeX and it affects the glyph shapes with some fonts
- `Magnification` simply rescales LaTeX's output proportionally

These are demonstrated in the MaTeX symbol reference page, under Examples -> Options.

Using `Magnification` won't for your problem.

Comment: Both work perfectly. I

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Magnification` option of MaTeX to manually change the size of the label within the `Callout` environment, as below:

```
Plot[Callout[x,MaTeX["A=2",FontSize->40,Magnification->2],Scaled[0.5]],{x,1,10},ImageSize->600]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However it seems that this does not work in my environment. I am using Mathematica 11.3 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm using MMA 11.2 in Windows. What is the error message that you got? What version of pdflatex are you using?

Comment: Have you tried to use `LabelStyle -> 40` as an option in Callout?

Comment: LabelStyle does not work for Callout. Here is the error message:Callout::copos: {LabelStyle->40} is not a valid position for the placement of callouts.

Comment: See my answer for why this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot decide whether this is a bug or not, but I can also reproduce the Vixillator's plot with the older version 11.2 in Ubuntu.

I checked both `InputForm` of the `Plot`. This seems to suggest that in 11.3 the relevant expressions for `MaTeX` are now wrapped with `DynamicModule`.
My limited investigation seems to show that, `DynamicModule` rescales the `MaTeX` object regardless of its actual size.

As a very ugly workaround, my tentative solution is as follows.

```
plot = Plot[
    Callout[x, f@MaTeX["A=2", FontSize -> 30], Scaled[0.5]], {x, 1, 
10}];

pos = plot // Cases[#, BSplineCurve[x___] -> x, Infinity] & // Last  //
   MaximalBy[ # [[1, 2 ]] &] // DeleteDuplicates // First //  ReplaceAll[ Offset[x_ , y_] :> Offset[ x  + {0, 15}, y]];
plot /. Text[Style[Rotate[f[ x__], ___], ___], ___] -> Inset[x, pos]
```

[image]